# ienumerable.sum null exception

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this issue I have with ienumerable.sum null exception.

Basically I have a class that pulls the sum of its child objects as a return.

Something like this:

Part Class:

```
public ICollection<ContractLineItem> ContractLineItems { get; set; }
public float TotalReceiptSpendLong { get { 
       return ContractLineItems.Sum(s => s.TotalReceiptSpend);  
} }
```

The contractlineitems class contains a ICollection to a receipts class which is totaled in the contractLineItems TotalReceiptSpend float. This works fine unless a contractlineitem has no receipts. It then throws a null exception. Is there a way to handle this best?

Comment: The collection wasn't initialized. The result should be 0 if the set was empty (but initialized).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Null-conditional Operators (C# and Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) along with [?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

```
 return ContractLineItems?.Sum(s => s?.TotalReceiptSpend ?? 0) ?? 0;
```

That way if any of the above referenced variables are null it will default to zero (`0`) and avoid the null reference error when calling `Sum`